# Converting a Perl Regex expression to Python

Tags: python, regex, perl

I'm trying to figure out the equivalent Python code for this Perl expression:

```perl
$pc =~ s/[[:^alnum:]]*//g;
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The regular expression means: remove all non-alphanumeric characters:

```
pc = re.sub('\W','', pc)
```

Comment: `\w` is not the same thing as alphanumeric, and `\W` isn't the opposite of alphanumeric.